# How highlight keyword using Regex in C# with special condition?

Tags: c#, regex, syntax-highlighting

I am a newbie with Regex so I need some help from my trouble.

This is my code:

```
private static string MatchEval(Match match)
{
    if (match.Groups[1].Success)    
        return "<strong>" + match.ToString() + "</strong>";
    return "";
}

private static string HighlightKeywords(string keywords, string text)
{   
    Regex r = new Regex(@", ?");
    keywords = "(" + r.Replace(keywords, @"|") + ")";   
    r = new Regex(keywords, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    return r.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(MatchEval));
}

string keywords = "group, person, club";
string text = "A fan club is a group that is dedicated to a well-known person";
```

when i call `HighlightKeywords(string keywords, string text);`

--> result:   `A fan <strong>club</strong> is a <strong>group</strong> that is dedicated to a well-known <strong>person</strong>`
**WORK CORRECT**

But if `string text = "A fan <strong>club</strong> is a group that is dedicated to a well-known person";`

--> result:  `A fan <strong></strong><strong>club</strong> is a <strong>group</strong> that is dedicated to a well-known <strong>person</strong>`

**WORK FAIL** (I want remove  `<strong></strong><strong>club</strong>`  with only `<strong>club</strong>`)

Another case `if text = "A fanclub is a group that is dedicated to a well-known person";`
 note: "**fanclub**" no space

result--> `A fan<strong>club</strong> is a <strong>group</strong> that is dedicated to a well-known <strong>person</strong>`

But i want get result --> `A fanclub is a <strong>group</strong> that is dedicated to a well-known <strong>person</strong>`

So Can any one help me how to do this ?

Comment: So what have you tried?  It does not appear that you have attempted to correct the malfunction yourself, as the fix should be trivial for someone that wrote what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
keywords = "\b(" + r.Replace(keywords, @"|") + ")\b";
```

\b - for non word character

Comment: If you are looking for non-strong matches, you can add look-behind: keywords = "(?<!<strong>)\b(" + r.Replace(keywords, @"|") + ")\b";

Answer (score 0):

Your keywords should be like this

```
string keywords = "\bgroup\b, \bperson\b, \bclub\b";
```

`\b` would create a boundary so `fanclub` would not match!